# pass the location of a an array in a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How can I pass the location of an array of pointers in a function in c i.e.
I have an `int* array[10];` and through a function I want to assign the `array[0]` to be the location of a particular number say, `5`. What should the argument of the function look like. I have tried:
`void insert(int* array);`
but it didn't work.

Comment: Please write the entire piece of code, with proper code formatting.

Comment: @kabanus what should I write as argument of a function to pass the location of an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are **always** passed as a pointer pointing to the beginning of the array, even if you don't write it explicitly. So given this declaration of an array from your question:

```
int *array[10];
```

Both the following functions will accept a pointer to such an array:

```
int foo(int *array[]);

int foo(int **array);
```

They are just equivalent and I would suggest you use the second form, because it makes it explicit what type really is passed to the function.

inside the function, you can access any element, because the indexers are define the same way on a *pointer to an array* as on the array itself:

```
int foo(int **array)
{
    int *sixthElement = array[5];
    // [...]
}
```

---

Additional stylistic note: In C, it's common practice to attach the `*` when declaring a pointer to the *identifier*, not to the *type*, ie better write

```
int *array[10];
```

instead of

```
int* array[10];
```

This is because in a C declaration, there's no such thing as a *pointer type*, there's a *pointer declarator* (consisting of the `*`, optional qualifiers and the identifier) and this declarator declares a variable to be a pointer to the specified type. It's a subtle difference, but if you ever try to declare more than one variable in one line (don't do this, it's just for explanation here), you will notice it:

```
int *a, b; // <- declares a as a pointer to int, b just as an int
```

Comment: "*Arrays are always passed as a pointer ...*" ... holding the value of the address of the array's 1st element.